# Styling of scroll bar doesn't work

Tags: c#, uwp, styles, scrollbar, scrollview

I write in C# UWP. `ScrollBar` Styling doesn't work, but some `ScrollViewer` Styling is good.

[image]

My code behind:

```
        Style ScrollBarStyle = new Style(typeof(ScrollBar));
        ScrollBarStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(ScrollBar.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)));

        Style ScrollViewerStyle = new Style(typeof(ScrollViewer));
        ScrollViewerStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(ScrollViewer.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)));

        Application.Current.Resources.Add(typeof(ScrollViewer), ScrollViewerStyle);
        Application.Current.Resources.Add(typeof(ScrollBar), ScrollBarStyle);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I write in C# UWP. ScrollBar Style is not work, but some style ScrollViewer Style is good .

The color of `ScrollBar` background is `Transparent` in the default style. And the `ScrollBar` background color will be covered by root `Grid`. So you just need to change the background color of the root grid in order to change `ScrollBar` background color.

**Usage**

```
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarBackgroundBrush" Color="Red" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarPanningBackgroundBrush" Color="Blue" />
  <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
      <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="7" />
      <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="7" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
      <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollBar">
                  <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="{StaticResource ScrollBarBackgroundBrush}">
                      <Grid x:Name="HorizontalPanningRoot" MinWidth="53">
                          <Rectangle
                              x:Name="HorizontalPanningThumb"
                              Height="2.4"
                              MinWidth="7"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                              Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBarPanningBackgroundBrush}" />
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid x:Name="VerticalPanningRoot" MinHeight="53">
                          <Rectangle
                              x:Name="VerticalPanningThumb"
                              Width="2.4"
                              MinHeight="7"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"
                              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                              Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBarPanningBackgroundBrush}" />
                      </Grid>
                      <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                              <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                              <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver" />
                              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                  <Storyboard>
                                      <DoubleAnimation
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="Root"
                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                          To="0.5"
                                          Duration="0" />
                                  </Storyboard>
                              </VisualState>
                          </VisualStateGroup>
                          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollingIndicatorStates">
                              <VisualState x:Name="TouchIndicator">
                                  <Storyboard>
                                      <FadeInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalPanningRoot" />
                                      <FadeInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalPanningRoot" />
                                  </Storyboard>
                              </VisualState>
                              <VisualState x:Name="MouseIndicator" />
                              <VisualState x:Name="NoIndicator">
                                  <Storyboard>
                                      <FadeOutThemeAnimation BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalPanningRoot" />
                                      <FadeOutThemeAnimation BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalPanningRoot" />
                                  </Storyboard>
                              </VisualState>
                          </VisualStateGroup>
                      </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                  </Grid>
              </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Set the root grid background color red.

[image]

Comment: It can be do with C# code? I want to change only color of scrollBar

Comment: It is not easy to change scrollbar background color by using c# code. If you want to change only color color of scrollBar. You could only change the `root` grid background color on the default [style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299150.aspx).

Comment: Thanks very much!